# addSubView does not work properly on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

This code should draw a line over cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (nil==cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSString *currentCourseName=[courseKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:currentCourseName];
    NSLog(currentCourseName);
    CGSize size = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font];
    CGFloat y = cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2;

    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,y,size.width, 3)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.textLabel addSubview:line];

    return cell;

}
```

But it seems I have to scroll it several times to see red lines.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the view that your are adding in that, rather than adding that in your - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` mehod, try using custom cell concept. That solved this issue in my `UITableView`.

[Creating a custom Table View Cell programmatically](http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)

[Custom Table View Cells in iPad Programming](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/custom-table-view-cells-in-ipad-programming/)

Comment: This would work for sure but it's just a workaround. The way to learn how to program is understanding the bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems in your code.

**First**

`CGFloat y = cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2`;

What is the `frame` of the `contentView` when you create the cell? If you are adding the subview to the label, use label's height.

```
CGSize size = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font];
UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, cell.textLabel.bounds.size.height / 2.0f - 1.5f, size.width, 3)];
line.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
```

**Second**

`[cell.textLabel addSubview:line];`

If a cell is reused, you are adding lines to cells when there is already a line. Check for `textLabel` subviews count first.

```
if (cell.textLabel.subviews.count == 0) {
    [cell.textLabel addSubview:line];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, for the first question, it's y position of line, does not matter. but the second problem, yes, you are right.

Comment: @Maysam The `y` position is probably what really matters. What if your line is outside of bounds of the label because your `y` is calculated incorrectly? `NSLog` your view frames and you will find the problems. Note that the size of `contentView` will be different when you create the cell and when you reuse the cell.

Comment: Please, `NSLog` the frame of your table, it's content view, it's text label and of the line before returning the cell of your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (nil==cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

     NSString *currentCourseName=[courseKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:currentCourseName];
    NSLog(currentCourseName);
    CGSize size = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font];
    CGFloat y = cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2;

    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,y,size.width, 3)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:line];

    }



    return cell;

}
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'contentView:'

Comment: try with [cell.contentView addSubview:line]

Comment: where you want to put line in UItableView ??

Comment: then where u want any condition ??